# No increment in memory usage for Python memory profiler

Tags: python, function, memory, profiling

I need to check how much memory a particular function is using during execution. I am using the memory_profiler from [Github repo](https://github.com/pythonprofilers/memory_profiler)
From some of the previous issues, it seems the behavior is a bit odd in the presence of loops. But I don't get the lack of increment in the memory in my log from lines 241-246. Each of those assignments should consume a pretty substantial amount of memory. Any suggestions? I am open to trying other libraries as well if you have any recommendations. Thanks!
[image]

Comment: "Each of those assignments should consume a pretty substantial amount of memory" - Why?? You just gave a name to some structure, there is nothing more happening - and no copy of data is made, if this is what you expected. It strongly suggest that you read the excellent https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Thanks for the helpful response! I understand what you are referring to. I think I need to .copy()  those dataframes to keep track of the memory used. Can you suggest what I should do about the Feature objects? I need to record the memory used by each identifier (variables, objects) initialized within the function. Any suggestions please? Thanks!